# AlertView design (to format it with textfields)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I'm using an AlertView to make a login/password screen. I have some problem to format the view correctly. I want to have a AlertView as high as that want (check printscreen if I'm not clear ) but I don't know how!

Here's the code I've made :

```
// Ask for Username and password.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login et mot de passe" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler"  otherButtonTitles:@"Sauvegarder", nil];


        // Adds a username Field
        textfieldName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
        textfieldName.placeholder = @"Login";
        [textfieldName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        textfieldName.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
        [textfieldName setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textfieldName setDelegate:self];
        [alertView addSubview:textfieldName];

        // Adds a username
        textfieldPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 90.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
        textfieldPassword.placeholder = @"Password";
        [textfieldPassword setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        textfieldPassword.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
        [textfieldPassword setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textfieldPassword setDelegate:self];
        [alertView addSubview:textfieldPassword];


        // Show alert on screen.
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
```

[image: printscreen]

Comment: And of I try alertView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,220);, the buttons "Annuler" and "Sauvegarder" Doesn't are underneath the alertview but still between the two fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alert view will adjust its contents (title and message) Try to add lines to the message:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login et mot de passe" 
    message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler"  
    otherButtonTitles:@"Sauvegarder", nil];
```

Comment: haha it's a great hack !

And I've new little question; can I impelment a method when someone press "Cancel"(Annuler) button ???

Comment: Of course. Why not? cancel button is just one of the buttons. in `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method you will receive a different index for that button.